# What will happen if we start the A320 engines but we don't wait for the amber crosses on the E/WD to disappear?

Tags: airbus-a320, engine-starting, sop

My logic is that we should wait for the sensors to register the present indications so we have a proper idea of what state the engine is in particularly the EGT if we have to consider a manual start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amber X's mean the FADEC is not yet energized. Once the X's disappear it means the FADEC is ready and can provide monitoring (even passive monitoring in a manual start).

Without FADEC there is no means to start the engine, as the valves are also FADEC controlled.

[image]
(A320 FADEC schematic.)

[image]
FADEC is needed even for manual start.